# onselect event in HTML <option></option> tag

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hi currently I have a list with onChange event in the `<select>...` Now I have two options as you can see in the code below. The option **55-rene** got the **selected="selected"** property so it is auto selected on page load. Now what I want is that when an option is auto selected (like it is below) this will work on selection (showSubCategories(this.value))

```
 <select name="category" id="category" size="12" 
                   onChange="showSubCategories(this.value)" >
    <option selected="selected" value="55-rene">Rene</option>
    <option value="55-kyle">Kyle</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the Change Event of the SELECT on the page load.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var category = document.getElementById("category");
        category.onchange();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where i need to put this please?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, then call `showSubCategories(document.getElementById('category').value)` when the page loads.

The `onChange` event won't fire when an item is set to be selected by default.

Comment: You need to put it in a function that will run when the page loads, as shown in @Cybernate's answer. `window.onload = function() { ...here... }`